# PWM Modes: Center Aligned and Left Aligned (current consumption)

Tags: microcontroller, arm

I have a question about PWM in STM32F051xxx Microcontrollers. I want to know if there is a difference regarding the current consumption of the microcontroller between the center aligned mode and edge aligned mode?

Comment: Why do you think there would be? I'm not saying there isn't, I'm just saying that it wouldn't ever occur to me personally that there might be a difference.

Comment: the averages would be the same either way, so unless you're talking about a tiny slice of time, "no".

Answer (score 0):

For a given duty cycle, no the current shouldn't be any different. The timer and CCR is still active for the entire period regardless of if it counts up and resets or counts up then back down (which I believe is the difference between left and center aligned).

I suppose the capture compare block makes an extra comparison in center aligned if I'm counting right, but that shouldn't increase current in any appreciable amount (if at all)